# Cramer's Rule python program crashing when I enter 0 for a and b

Tags: python, python-3.x

If I enter `0` for `a` and `b`, the program crashes.  I am still trying to figure out how to modify it.

```
a = int(input("Enter number for a: "))
b = int(input("Enter number for b: "))
c = int(input("Enter number for c: "))
d = int(input("Enter number for d: "))
e = int(input("Enter number for e: "))
f = int(input("Enter number for f: "))

x = (e*d-b*f)/(a*d-b*c)
y = (a*f-e*c)/(a*d-b*c)

if a*d-b*c==0:
    print("The equation has no solution")

else:
    print("x is: ", x, "and y is: ", y)
```

Comment: You're checking for possible division by zero *after doing it twice* - why not before?

Comment: As @jonrsharpe says do the check before computing x and y.

Comment: Makes total sense.  Thank you.

Comment: if a*d-b*c==0:
    print("The equation has no solution")


else:
    x = (e*d-b*f)/(a*d-b*c)
    y = (a*f-e*c)/(a*d-b*c)
    print("x is: ", x, "and y is: ", y)

Comment: Calculate the denominator once, then check and use it or print error message.

Comment: Thank you all.  It makes sense now.  Being new, these small programs get confusing when you're staring at them for hours and have little experience.  You've been a great help.